How did I get the git branch to appear in iTerm2?
My iTerm2 terminal tells me what git branch I'm on. I like this feature a lot, but it seems like this is not a default feature. I don't remember doing anything specific to get this. I've checked my bash profile and zshrc file, and they don't indicate that I've configured anything specific for iTerm2. How did I get this? I'd like to recreate this for other machines.
My terminal

Check your PS1 shell/environment variable.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branch+PS1

From your screenshot, I can not conclude that the terminal would tell you anything. I can see that your shell is telling you this information, but you don't even say what shell you are running, let alone how you have configured it. If you go to a new machine, you will have to recreate the configuration for the respective shell you are using it. If you are brave, you can try to just copy the files over to the new system. I personally always take a change of machine as opportunity to go manually through my conf files and see what I want to keep.
